# PHP Как заменить строку в зависимости от её значения?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Переменная `$parameter['pay']` может получать значения в виде наименований:
Наличные
Безналичный

**Необходимо заменить эти значения на цифры:**

Наличные = 1

Безналичный = 2

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order');
function send_order( $order_id ){

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_data = $order->get_data()

    $parameter['pay'] = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
}
```

В итоге параметр `$parameter['pay']` будет иметь значение 1 или 2.

Пробовала такой вариант, но выдаёт ошибку синтаксиса.

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order');
function send_order( $order_id ){

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_data = $order->get_data()

    $parameter['pay'] = $payment_method_code;

    $payment_method_code = $order_data['payment_method_title'];

    $cash = str_replace("Наличные", "1", "$payment_method_code");
    $terminal = str_replace("Безналичный", "2", "$payment_method_code");

    print_r ($parameter['pay'])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    "Наличные" => 1,
    "Безналичный" => 2
);
$parameter['pay'] = $arr[$parameter['pay']];
```

сначала объявили массив содержащий все ассоциации что нам нужны, а после заменили содержимое нашей переменной значением из массива, ключ которого соответствует начальному значению нашей переменной.

только если у вас изменится форма и будут отправляться другие строки - это перестанет работать. лучше переверстайте форму так, что бы сразу приходили цифровые значения и не было зависимостей от текста.

Comment: Спасибо, но вы забыли строку `$order_data['payment_method_title'];` - она получает первоначальные данные.

Comment: я описал сам принцип как текст заменить на ассоциативное значение. у вас, кстати, в приведённом коде (который выдаёт ошибку) не плохо бы поменять местами первые 2 строки имеющие `$payment_method_code`, т.е. на строке `$parameter['pay'] = $payment_method_code;` переменной `$payment_method_code` ещё не существует, соответственно и `$parameter['pay']` будет пустой

Comment: В таком случае вернее будет так как мне кажется:
    $arr = array(
        "Наличные" => 1,
        "Безналичный" => 2
    );

    $parametr['pay'] = $arr[$order_data['payment_method_title']];